# Do I have FlashDevelop configured wrong?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

I have two machines I run FlashDevelop on, both have worked well up until recently.  A couple of months ago my desktop (Win 7) stopped showing the Output window at the bottom of the screen when I did a compile and just did "Build Failed". I was busy with other things so I set that aside, now I need to figure out what's going on.

The laptop (Win 8) is running FlashDevelop 4.6.0.18. If I go to Tools-Settings I see the following:

Tools->Settings->AS3Context->Installed Flex SDKs

```
 Flex 4.6.0, AIR 3.9
 Flex 4.6.0, AIR 3.1
 Flex 4.6.0, AIR 15.0
 AIR 15.0
```

The desktop, which is running FD 4.6.4.1, shows this:

Tools->Settings->AS3Context->Installed Flex SDKs

```
 Flex 4.6.0, AIR 3.1
 Flex 4.6.0, AIR 15.0
 AIR 15.0
```

When I run a compile, I no longer get "Build Failed", but I do get this:

"Could not locate lib\mxmlc.jar or lib\mxmlc-cli.jar in Flex SDK."

Did a search for \lib\mxmlc-cli.jar and found the following:

c:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop4.5\Tools\ascsdk\lib\mxmlc-cli.jar
c:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\ascsdk\15.0.0\lib\mxmlc-cli.jar

I have another copy of \lib\mxmlc-cli.jar in a slightly different directory, if I rename the directory I go back to "Build Failed".

I keep hoping this has a simple answer, but I haven't found it yet. Any clues?

Added note- I did a re-install and ran AppMan, got an error on installing Flex SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to get rid of FlashDevelop on the Win 7 machine and then go through the whole re-installation process. That worked. Still not sure what the problem was with the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with setting up FD on my new win 8.1 machine. It did not want to compile, always complaining about missing sdks and that missing jars.

It all happened when I imported my settings from the win7-machine. The SDK-specifications are also imported, but in my case they differ on both machines.

So I had to re-configurate the sdks manually in
Tools->Program Settings->AS3Context->Installed Flex SDKs.

In the Enlistings-editor (or so) I removed all sdks and re-added them (only specifying the absolute path of each sdk, for the name and version was added automatically).

If you got Flash installed you should also check the "User Classpath" entries in AS3Context.

Hope, that helps.